# How to handle running Cucumber features within Ruby method?

Tags: ruby, methods, initialization, cucumber

I am using a `AfterConfiguration` hook to run some setup config before my tests start, however the issue that I am faced with is that when I run my methods one of them will run a set of feature files using backticks in a Ruby method, which in turn seems to re-initialize cucumber and repeat the process, so I am stuck in a loop

```
AfterConfiguration  do
   EnvironmentSetup::TestUsers.create_test_users
end

module EnvironmentSetup
  class TestUsers
    def self.create_test_users
    # other logic here
    `cucumber "#{path_to_feature}"` # Use backticks to run cucumber scripts in a subshell
    end 
  end
end
```

So when this is executed it goes back to the beginning and runs it all my other logic again

Is there a way to only run this once, or ignore the AfterConfiguration on the second loop? declare a global variable?

I have also tried

```
AfterConfiguration  do
 if defined? $a == nil
   EnvironmentSetup::RedisUsers.check_redis_users
   EnvironmentSetup::TestUsers.create_test_users
 end
```

end

```
module EnvironmentSetup
  class TestUsers
    def self.create_test_users
    # other logic here
    $a = true
    `cucumber "#{path_to_feature}"` # Use backticks to run cucumber scripts in a subshell
    end 
  end
end
```

but I'm guessing that the variable set is not being carried across when re-initializing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting Environment variable:

```
AfterConfiguration do
  return if ENV['CUCUMBER_CONFIGURED'] == 'yes'

  EnvironmentSetup::TestUsers.create_test_users
  ENV['CUCUMBER_CONFIGURED'] = 'yes'
end
```

And run cucumber something like this:

```
CUCUMBER_CONFIGURED='no'; cucumber ...
```